# Can't get Binance ThreadWebsocketManager to display price stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance-api-client

I am currently trying to stream live prices from, Binance but after running the code I see a blank screen even though the program is running.

Below is the code:

```
import os
from binance.client import Client
import time
from binance import ThreadedWebsocketManager
from binance import ThreadedDepthCacheManager

api_key = os.environ.get('api_key')
api_secret = os.environ.get('api_secret')
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

def main():

    symbol = 'BTCUSDT'
    twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
    
    #Start is required to initialise its internal loop
    twm.start()

    def handle_socket_message(msg):
        print(f"message type: {msg['e']}")
        print(msg)

    twm.start_kline_socket(callback=handle_socket_message, symbol=symbol)
    
    twm.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Please edit your question so the code block appears correctly. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue recently.

for some reason, I couldn't get any response from the ThreadedWebSocketManager.

While searching for answer I encountered your question and with further research I found out that it's a [known issue](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/892). **Seems like ThreadedWebSocketManager doesn't work well with Python3.10.** I downgraded to **Python3.9** and it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from binance.streams import ThreadedWebsocketManager
from binance.streams import ThreadedDepthCacheManager

api_key = os.environ.get('api_key')
api_secret = os.environ.get('api_secret')

def main():
    symbol = 'BTCUSDT'        
    
    def handle_socket_message(msg):
        print(f"message type: {msg['e']}")
        print(msg)
    twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
    twm.start()

    twm.start_kline_socket(callback=handle_socket_message, symbol=symbol)
    twm.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    while True:
        pass
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).